# Creating A Thatched/Rattan Material?

Tags: texturing, materials

Trying to make a thatched material (for my lamp shade). Like a rattan type look. Can't figure this one out for the life of me. Here's an example: http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/rattan-texture-5839027.jpg

How would you make something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a close up?

Comment: @someonewithpc Yes sir. I mean, not really close, but it's for game art so potentially it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get this would be:

- Add a plane, in *Edit Mode* subdivide <kbd>W</kbd>
- Poke <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>

This should look like:

[image]

- In top view <kbd>Numpad-7</kbd> rotate 45° <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd>
- Scale along X-Axis <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>
- Select one of the new (poked) vertices and select *Amount of connecting edges* from the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> popup
- Move the selected vertices upward <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>

[image]

In *Object Mode* add a Subdivision Surface* modifier with subdivisions set to 3:

[image]

- Bake the normals of the resulting mesh to an unwraped plane and use the image as normal map.