# Ways to create woven rattan garden furniture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, cloth-simulation, normal-map

I'm working on a scene and need to model a garden chair with woven material similar to this: 
https://www.bau-outdoors.co.uk/shop/outdoor-furniture/garden-dining-chairs/montreux-woven-rattan-garden-chairs/
I have modelled all the frame of the chair but am struggling to come up with any ideas of how to create the fabric. The frame is alot more curved than the image so would need more work to get it wrapped around. Would it be possible to use a normal map and a texture or is there a way to use arrays or a cloth sim to get it to wrap around properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am replicating an image so would really like to keep it accurate. The chair is not the focal point so does not have to be perfect.

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/creating-a-thatched-rattan-material

Comment: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tce6GqNyJ2A)